# Rails 4, Stripe Integration, Webhook Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have a rails application which is Integrated with Stripe, I'm using the stripe_events gem to handle webhooks.

However, when a webhook is recieved I'm getting the following error.

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for ActiveSupport::Notifications::Fanout::Subscribers::Timed:0x007fde814aaee0

stripe_event (1.5.0) lib/stripe_event.rb:28:in `instrument'
stripe_event (1.5.0) app/controllers/stripe_event/webhook_controller.rb:12:in `event'
actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
```

Does anyone know what this is referring to?

Here is my stripe_events.rb file

```
StripeEvent.event_retriever = lambda do |params|
  return nil if StripeWebhook.exists?(stripe_id: params[:id])
  StripeWebhook.create!(stripe_id: params[:id])
  Stripe::Event.retrieve(params[:id])
end

StripeEvent.configure do |events|
  events.subscribe 'customer.subscription.created' do |event|   
    puts 'testing 123'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem...

turns out I was missng some code in # config/initializers/stripe.rb

```
StripeEvent.configure do |events|
  events.subscribe 'charge.failed' do |event|
    # Define subscriber behavior based on the event object
    event.class       #=> Stripe::Event
    event.type        #=> "charge.failed"
    event.data.object #=> #<Stripe::Charge:0x3fcb34c115f8>
  end

  events.all do |event|
    # Handle all event types - logging, etc.
  end
end
```